# Exception when serializing to XML (but not to JSON)

Tags: php, xml, symfony, xml-serialization, symfony-3.3

I'm using `Symfony 3.3` serializer. This code:

```
$serialized = $this->serializer->serialize($input, "json");
```

returns:

```
{
    "title": "dsd",
    "description": null,
    "source": null,
    "tags": null,
    "objectId": null,
    "attributes": {
        "sdffds": "sdffsdfsd",
        "fsfdsfd": "sdfsdfsdf"
    },
    "features": [],
    "lifecycleStart": null,
    "lifecycleEnd": null,
    "attachments": {
        "20170625194534-595012dee26c8": {
            "original": "favicon (1).ico",
            "filename": "favicon (1).ico",
            "size": "318",
            "title": null,
            "description": null,
            "reader": null
        }
    }
}
```

Unforutnately, running

```
$serialized = $this->serializer->serialize($input, "xml");
```

will throw an exception:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception DOMException: "Invalid Character Error" at /www/site/ui/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Encoder/XmlEncoder.php line 454
```

I'm pretty sure I didn't include any funny character. Do you have any idea whether I'm doing anything wrong or could it be a symfony bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because of `20170625194534-595012dee26c8`. XML element name cannot start with number. See: [The Naming of Parts](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/07/25/namingparts.html) article on XML.com.